# CSS Locator not recognising an element in Protractor Test?

Tags: css, angular, jasmine, protractor

In my Protractor test below, I am trying to count the number of div's using the CSS locator:

```
let list = element.all(by.css('div[class="ag-header-cell ag-header-cell-sortable"]'));
expect(list.count()).toBe(11);
```

As you can see from the below screenshot, there are 11 div's with this class, but for some reason my test is only counting 10. So my test is failing with the below error message:

> Expected 10 to be 11

[image]

To see which div wasn't being recognised, I logged the text of each div:

```
element.all(by.css('div[class="ag-header-cell ag-header-cell-sortable"]')).each((it) => {
    it.getText().then((text) => {
        console.log('Text', text);
    })
})
```

The div with `col-id='Ni'` isn't being recognised for some reason, even though it does have the CSS class I'm specifying in the test.

Can someone please tell me why this is happening?

Comment: I can assume the page doesn't load fully at the time when you do `count`. Try to give it a longer wait

Comment: Hi @SergeyPleshakov I tried that before posting, but just to make sure I added `browser.sleep(20000);` before assigning the list variable, but still getting the same error message.

Comment: super weird, likely an error in your script. Is this page publicly accesable? I'd take a look

Comment: I know @SergeyPleshakov, it drove me mad :) my answer below is retrieving all the values then, which makes it even stranger! Unfortunately, it's behind a username & password so I'm unable to share it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow managed to get the locator working with this function:

```
element.all(by.css('div.ag-header-cell'))
    .map(function (cell) {
        return cell.getText();
    })
    .then(function (cellValues) {
        expect(cellValues).toEqual(["1st Expected Result", "2nd Expected Result"]);
});
```

This captures all 11 values that I wasn't able to get using the code in my question.